Is masking output for partially labelled data an acceptable practice?
Minimal Context
Given the scarcity of labelled data I'm writing a multihead-NN to predict multiple partially labelled properties.
Some these aren't of interest but make the backbone is robust; later on, the NN can be used independently for each head.
In practice, at the output, a mask (binary vector) will zero unavailable label-columns in turn making that loss_i=0.

Comment
This is preferable to just a single output head:

it will be less of a large network to 'export'.
It will also easily allow for separate Losses,

Questions

Is masking output for partially labelled data an acceptable practice?

If this is a reasonable idea, it must be quite common. But I wonder whether there is a name for it, and maybe any 'canonical' paper?

It and may need a way to normalise the gradients?


My idea is to use it to train with Graph Neural Networks, with multi-head property predictor.
